# Bootstrap 3 modal popup disappear on button click

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I used bootstrap 3 modal dialog for search function in my asp.net inventory application.When I press the search button on my  modal content whole popup up dialog went disappeared.I want to lock the the modal dialog in my current page window.How can I resolve this using bootstrap.I tried putting data-backdrop: static.But it's still not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try also passing the

```
{keyboard: false}
```

Option as well as data-backdrop: false. Technically speaking data-backdrop should be solving your problem. Is theres something that makes your project unique?